# how do use a foreach loop with a datalist in html

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a drop down datalist in html, but instead of hardcoding all the different option tags, I want the drop down menu to display the contents of an array.  when I run the code, its just an empty box.  I'm a beginner learning from whatever resources I can find, any help is appreciated.

```
<body>
<h2>select a car model</h2>
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
<?php
$cars = [1 => 'supra', 'skyline', 'GTO', 'corvette', '370z'];

 echo' <label for="car">Choose your car:</label>';
  echo '<input list="cars" name="car" id="car"> ';
 echo ' <datalist id="cars">';
 foreach($cars as $key => $value){
     echo '<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>\n';
 }
 
  echo '</datalist>';
 echo  '<input type="submit">';
  ?>
</form>

</body>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define array correctly, try `$cars = ['supra', 'skyline', 'GTO', 'corvette', '370z'];`

Comment: Why have you added `1=>` in the $cars array?

Comment: that => was left over from another example, I forgot to take it out.  it works now! thank you!  I'm not using JS, just html and php.

Comment: Glad its working for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the code

```php
<body>
    <h2>select a car model</h2>
    <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <?php
    $cars = [1 => 'supra', 'skyline', 'GTO', 'corvette', '370z'];

    echo' <label for="car">Choose your car:</label>';
    echo '<input list="cars" name="car" id="car"> ';
    echo ' <datalist id="cars">';
    foreach($cars as $key => $value){
        //some bug fix here
        echo "<option value='${key}'>$value</option>\n";
    }
    
    echo '</datalist>';
    echo  '<input type="submit">';
    ?>
    </form>

</body>
```

and which js library you used for the drop down list